# How JVM treats reference variables?

Tags: java, reference, jvm

Just want to know whether this statement is true or not:

For these lines of code:

```
Person Bob = new Person("Bob W.", 30);
System.out.println(Bob.name);
```

An Object Person is created and its memory address or a kind of reference is sent to Bob, the reference variable . Next, when we call "Bob.name", the JVM looks at the "address" held by Bob and goes there to look at the Person Object. Then JVM looks at Bob's name and prints it!

Thanks!

Comment: Right. If the name is a `String`, then `Bob.name` is in turn also a reference to a string object, of course. Internally the JVM is free to optimize things if the semantics don't change. So it e.g. could place the `Person` object directly on the stack if it can prove that the reference stored in `Bob` can't leave the function where the object was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects in Java are accessed via their references (different from primitive access!). The variable `bob` is a reference to an instance of the `Person` class. Memory allocation/disposal of instances will be handled by the JVM, and the instance data will be kept alive by the JVM as long as there exist strong references to that instance (ie `Person bob = new ...` declares a strong reference to the newly created `Person` instance).

> An Object Person is created and its memory address or a kind of reference is sent to Bob, the reference variable

It would be more correct to say that an "An instance of the Person Object is created", but yes, all variables used for objects in Java are reference variables. Calling `new` will return the reference to the instance created. There can be many reference variables which point to a single instance. For example, in the following code snippet we can have two references pointing to a single instance:

```
Person bob = new Person("Bob W.", 30);
Person bob2 = bob;
```

> Next, when we call "Bob.name", the JVM looks at the "address" held by Bob and goes there to look at the Person Object.

Exactly. After code is compiled, the JVM bytecode will use the instruction `getfield` to access the `name` field. This instruction requires an object reference and the field reference. In this case `bob.name` will use `bob` as the `objectref` and use `Person#name` as the `fieldref`.