# The relationship between references and variables

Tags: reference

Is the reference data a concrete computer technology（based on Memory addressing） or an abstract concept（can achieved in many ways）

```
or
```

can you explain how the reference data is implemented in computer language

please! please! I'm very confused

Comment: Hello, this very much depends on the computer language you are using, could you please specify what you mean?

Comment: @AlexAngel hi！I am using java . I am curious how the reference data type is designed and the details of their structure in memory

Comment: If you are talking about the schematics of the java language in regards to your question, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010236/11192546 If you are talking about how the java bytecode interpreter works with [references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137643/11192546) and [variables](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/322058) then I suggest you read [JVM SE Spec 16 - 2.4. Reference Types and Values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.4),

Comment: and [Java Language Specification SE 16 - 12.3.3. - Resolution of Symbolic References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3.3)

Comment: Thank you! You helped me find the same topic! But their answers are all ‘figures’. I am looking for a more professional answer

Comment: I'm not doing your homework for you